# Is there any way to format the numbers in output file?

Tags: c++, file-io, formatting

I made a program which outputs certain number to an external file. To display the output inside the program I would simply use codes like "setw" and setprecision but I couldn't format my numbers in output file with these codes. Am I missing something?Or is there any trick to do it?

n can be upto 999.

```
for (int k=0; k<n, k++)
    for (int l=0; l<n; l++)
         sqrfile<<setw(4)<<box[k][l];
    sqrfile<<endl;
```

Comment: What is your expected output?  What output are you getting instead?

Comment: so you hope for one file of up to 998001 numbers on one line to give you a nice formatting...? Well, it will be up to 998001 numbers on that line!

Comment: It's basically I have to display a magic square and n is the order. The order can be up to 999. I need to display a "beautiful" square in the output file. I just couldn't figure out the number formatting

Comment: C++ isn't Python! You need to figure out how to create a block statement.